# Call Control real-time notifications

Tags: microsoft-teams

Is it possible today, to get real-time notifications about call control events (ring,accept,hangup, and callerId-CDR for PSTN and teams-S4B calls) ?  using a bot or connector ?

Comment: Currently you can get only Event mentioned in [Bot events documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/concepts/bots/bots-notifications).

Comment: @Wajeed-MSFT please,  is it so difficult to confirm if currently we can or can't  get call control events (at least accept-hangup, with caller ID)  for PSTN callls in MS Teams ?  and if  we can't  what is the roadmap about them?  I can't read the whole documentation and it is not focused.

Answer (score 0):

Three days after my question,  Microsoft  announced in MSIgnite 2018 the public preview of the [calls and online meetings API in Microsoft Graph](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/calls-api-overview). It seems the way to go.  [What's new in Teams - Ignite Edition](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/Microsoft-Teams-Blog/What-s-new-in-Teams-Ignite-Edition/ba-p/252531) Of cource, we need much more information about and help.